# Auto scaling with AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Created one EC2 instance from Amazon AWS. After did the changes on the instance, make one AMI from it.

Using the AMI, I have created on Auto scaling group to create one instance When CPU hit 70 %. Once done the Auto scaling  creation, its create one instance at the end. So I deleted the Old one and move the traffic to the new instance.

but the problem here is , Auto scaling is not working when the CPU hits a threshold limit. Should I need to keep the Old machine which I used to create a AMI image ?.

Can  anyone give your suggestion on this ?.

Thanks.

Comment: Server-related questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Try [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: Check that you have set up the scaling policy correctly, for example average CPU utilization >= 70% for at least 1 consecutive period of 5 minutes. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/policy_creating.html#policy-creating-asg-console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dig more into the Auto scaling group policy and configuration manual, I got fixed this problem.

There is no issues if you delete the instance which is used to create AMI. Problem I made is enter "Scale between 1 and 1" in the Auto Group policy config. After changed this value to 1 and 2. its start work.

Attached screen shot what changes I did.

Note : Cloud Watch Also important on the Auto scaling.

Thanks.